# Implementing a REST api which switches between XML and JSON in Servlets

Tags: java, json, tomcat, rest

Twitter's REST api allows you to append a JSON or XML at the end of the URI.

e.g.

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.json
http://twitter.com/statuses/public_timeline.xml
```

In the context of servlet, statuses will be the webapp context name & public_timeline.json is mapped to some servlet. I want to maintain one servlet to do the dispatch. Can this be done in servlets ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Take a look at the web.xml file you may use a pattern like:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <url-pattern>public_timeline.*</servlet-class>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-class>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I think you can even use public_timeline.[json|xml]

Answer (score 2):

The URL mapping in Servlet only supports extension matching, not prefix matching. So this doesn't work,

```
  <url-pattern>/public_timeline.*</servlet-class>
```

Here is my suggestion,

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <url-pattern>/*</servlet-class>
  <servlet-name>YourServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In the servlet, you can do this,

```
    String path = request.getPathInfo();

    if (path == null) return;

    int index = path.indexOf('/');
    String api;
    if (index < 0) 
        api = path;
    else
        api = path.substring(index+1);

        if (api.equals("public_timeline.json"))
            // Process it as JSON

        if (api.equals("public_timeline.xml"))
            // Process it as XML
```

Most APIs use a format parameter to indicate response format. I think that's the better way.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, if you are using JAXRS for your rest services, annotate your REST service method like:

```
@Path("/statuses/public_timeline{fileExt}")
```

Then add the following to you method argument:

```
@PathParam(value="fileExt") String fileExt
```

The the fileExt variable would be your extension.  I think that would be a standard REST way to do it using JAXRS

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple glob-matching in url-pattern:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>public_timeline</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>your.package.PublicTimelineServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <url-pattern>/public_timeline.*</servlet-class>
  <servlet-name>public_timeline</servlet-class>
</servlet-mapping>
```